# Why does gitk show that I have uncommited changes but doesn't show them in Ubuntu WSL?

Tags: git, file-permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mingw-w64, gitk

When I open `gitk` from MINGW64 / git bash it says I have uncommited changes in the form of changes to file permissions.

But I'm doing all my commit's from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS WSL...so how do I stop that from happening?  I really don't care about the permissions being changed in this case; it's not like I'm using `git` with `etckeeper`.

It displays alot of this:

```
------------- <path to file>
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

Comment: If you change the file in Windows there maybe some issue with line endings, e.g. CRLF in Windows and LF in *nix.

Comment: @Biswapriyo It's all `old mode 100755` / `new mode 100644` in the uncommited changes.